# How do I remove the 'Adobe Notification Client' process that runs on startup?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-creative-cloud

I find it really annoying that this is process running — among loads of others on startup — just because I installed Adobe Creative Cloud. It’s like it installs a dozen Trojans on my system that surely don’t need to be running when I’m not using Adobe products like Photoshop?

I disabled all the service-based ones, but I can’t figure out how to remove or disable this specific one. What can be done?

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to [Dwinky’s post in the official Adobe Support forums](https://community.adobe.com/t5/enterprise-teams/disable-notification-manager-for-adobe-creative-cloud/td-p/10931966?page=1), you can use the following command:

```
Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers *AdobeNotificationClient* | Remove-AppxPackage -AllUsers
```

It seems to work. Just run that command in an elevated (administrator) Powershell. It should complete without error and the process will be removed from your system.

I’m not 100% certain that it won’t come back (they always seem to!), but it’s clean for now.